# Cannot launch Anaconda-Navigator under Ubuntu system with error FileNotFound

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I launch terminal and run anaconda-navigator I can see the green icon, however forever paused with the following details in the terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 550, in setup
    self.post_setup(conda_data=conda_data)
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 587, in post_setup
    self.tab_home.setup(conda_data)
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 171, in setup
    self.set_applications(applications, packages)
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 206, in set_applications
    apps = self.api.process_apps(applications, prefix=self.current_prefix)
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 865, in process_apps
    app = app(config=self.config, process_api=self._process_api)
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 111, in __init__
    super(PyCharmProApp, self).__init__(
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(BasePyCharmApp, self).__init__(
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/base.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.set_up_app_directory_path()
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/base.py", line 59, in set_up_app_directory_path
    self.app_directory_path = self._get_linux_installation_directory()
  File "/home/jichao/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 62, in _get_linux_installation_directory
    for dir_name in os.listdir(root):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked to see if the `opt` folder was in the root directory. It was not. I opened terminal and typed:

```
cd /
sudo makedir opt
```

This appeared to solve the issue for me.